# Concurrent HashMap iterator:How safe is it for Threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I used concurrent hashmap for creating a matrix. It indices ranges to 100k. I have created 40 threads. Each of the thread access those elements of matrices and modifies to that and write it back of the matrix as:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>> matrix = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>>(25);

for (Entry(Integer,ArrayList<Double>)) entry: matrix.entrySet())
    upDateEntriesOfValue(entry.getValue());
```

I did not found it thread safe. Values are frequently returned as null and my program is getting crashed. Is there any other way to make it thread safe.Or this is thread safe and i have bug in some other places. One thing is my program does not crash in single threaded mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `iterator` is indeed thread-safe for the `ConcurrentHashMap`.

But what is not thread-safe in your code is the `ArrayList<Double>` you seem to update! Your problems might come from this data structure.

You may want to use a [concurrent data structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) adapted to you needs.

Comment: do you suggest me to use synchronized arraylist?

Comment: synchronized arraylist will work as it is only accessed by one thread at a time. But depending on the way you add and read elements, you may want to try a ``LinkedBlockingQueue`` or even one the java.util.concurrent.atomic arrays if you know the size in advance and want to access specific indexes. It mostly depends on your needs.

Comment: Did you try a synchronized array list to start with? Did it solve your problems?

Comment: i used **Atomic Doulbe Array** instead of **arraylis** from the package **gauva** .Still i am having the same problem

Comment: Then your problem comes from somewhere else. Try to isolate the piece of code containing the issue and post a new question if you're stuck.

Comment: sure .. i will be posting question.

Answer (score 2):

Using a map for a matrix is really inefficient, and the way you have used it, it won't even support sparse arrays particularly well.

I suggest you use a double[][] where you lock each row (or column if that is better)  If the matrix is small enough you may be better of using only one CPU as this can save you quite a bit of overhead.

I would suggest you create no more threads than you have cores. For CPU intensive tasks, using more thread can be slower, not faster.

> Matrix is 100k*50 at max

EDIT: Depending on the operation you are performing, I would try to ensure you have the shorter dimension first so you can process each long dimension in a different thread efficiently.

e.g

```
double[][] matrix = new double[50][100*1000];
for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
   final double[] line = matrix[i];
   executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          synchronized(line) {
              processOneLine(line);
          }
       }
   });
}
```

This allows all you thread to run concurrently because they don't share any data structures.  They can also access each double efficiently because they are continuous in memory and stored as efficiently as possible. i.e. 100K doubles uses about 800KB, but `List<Double>` uses 2800KB and each value can be randomly arranged in memory which means your cache has to work much harder.

> thanks but in fact i have 80 cores in total

To uses 80 core efficiently you might want to break the longer lines in two or four so you can keep all the cores busy, or find a way to perform more than one operation at a time.

Comment: i have enough cores. That is not major issue for me. Matrix is **100k*50** at max

Comment: Not many people have exactly 40 cores.  I suggest you use `Runtime.availableProcessors()` to ensure you are using all your cpus.

Comment: What model of machine supports 80 cores. Often its a number like 16 quad cores or 16 hex cores. Do you have 16 * 5 cores?

Answer (score 1):

The`ConcurrentHashMap` will be thread safe for accesses into the Map, but the `Lists` served out need to be `thread-safe`, if multiple threads can operate on the same List instances concurrently so use a `thread-safe` `list` while modifying.

In your case working on  `ConcurrentHashMap` is tread-safe but when thread goes to `ArrayList` this is not `synchronized` and hence multiple threads can access it simultaneously which makes it non thread-safe. either you can use `synchronized block` where you are performing modification in list